# Counting words in a text file via python

Tags: python, string, parsing, python-3.x

Below is a project I have been assigned in which I must write a program that opens a text file and counts the words in the file. Below I have outlined a program that is supposed to set `previous = False` for any cases of white space (ie. spaces, tabs, \n) and sets `previous = True` for any other case. When there exists a case where `previous = False` and there is no white space detected (beginning of a word), it will add 1 to the `wordCount`. However, my output shows slightly different results (shown below). Restrictions are I cant use .split() functions, must be done by hand. Being this is a school assignment, I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, but merely teach me a bit and explain what I'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
"""
title: findWords.py
author: Riley Lloyd
"""

#import necessary libraries
import turtle as bob

def init():
    """

    :return:
    """
    pass

def countWords ( textFileName ):
    """

    :param textFileName:
    :return:
    """
    previous = False
    wordCount = 0
    for text in open(textFileName):
        print(text)
        if text == " ":
            previous = False
        elif text == "\n":
            previous = False
        elif text == "\t":
            previous = False
        else:
            if previous == False:
                wordCount += 1
            previous = True
    print(wordCount)


def main():
    """

    :return:
    """
    init()
    countWords(input("Enter filename: "))

main()
```

Results:

```
Enter filename: some.txt
Words make up other words.

This is a line.

  Sequences of words make sentences.

I like words but I don't like MS Word.

    There's another word for how I feel about MSWord: @#%&

1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `with open(filename) as f:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating over the open file -

```
for text in open(textFileName):
```

When you do that, you are actually iterating over the lines of the file , so in first iteration `text` would be the first line of the file, in second iteration `text` would be the second line of the file, etc. But, your logic is written such that it expects `text` would be a each character in the file.

If your file is not large I would suggest you to do `.read()` and iterate over that. Example -

```
def countWords ( textFileName ):
    """

    :param textFileName:
    :return:
    """
    with open(textFileName) as f:
        texts = f.read()
        previous = False
        wordCount = 0
        for text in texts:
            print(text)
            if text == " ":
                previous = False
            elif text == "\n":
                previous = False
            elif text == "\t":
                previous = False
            else:
                if previous == False:
                    wordCount += 1
                previous = True
        print(wordCount)
```

I have used `with` statement to open the file, you should also use `with` statements to open the file, it will automatically handle closing of the files for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, another restriction is that we can't use any functionality not yet discussed in class so that rules out `.partition()` and `.read()`. Is there any workaround to `.read()` or should I hope it's accepted and risk losing the points?

Comment: A workaround to using `.read()` would be to read line by line like you do, but then again do a nested `for` loop for reading the characters from it , and then your logic.